# How to transform this piece of code using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

In order to defend against XSS attacks, I wrote a class that extends from `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and overrides the `getParameterValues` method, the code is shown below:

```java
    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
        Map<String, String[]> parameters = super.getParameterMap();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        if (parameters != null) {
            for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
                String[] values = parameters.get(key);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    String value = values[i];
                    if (!StrUtil.hasEmpty(value)) {
                        value = HtmlUtil.filter(value);
                    }
                    values[i] = value;
                }
                map.put(key, values);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

I'm wondering if this piece of code could be transformed using Java Stream because I see a lot of `if` condition judgement and `for` loop.
Methods:`StrUtil.hasEmpty` and `HtmlUtil.filter` are come from here: [Hutool](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.hutool/hutool-all/5.4.0)

Any suggestions to improve the performance of this code are welcome.

Comment: It is important to bring out your attempt in solving your problem

Comment: Please show the attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can make elegent solution with streams plus map / filter but it will be re-allocating the memory footprint of the request data creating many new for objects for Map, N * Map.Entry, N * String[], and filtered strings and other intermediate steps.

Alternatively consider simplifying the logic of your existing loop just to fix each `String[]` value in place and return the existing map:

```
public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
    Map<String, String[]> parameters = super.getParameterMap();
    if (parameters != null) {
        for (String[] values : parameters.values()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                String value = values[i];
                if (!StrUtil.hasEmpty(value)) {
                    values[i] = HtmlUtil.filter(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
        Map<String, String[]> parameters = super.getParameterMap();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        if (parameters != null) {
            map = parameters.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    v -> Arrays.stream(v.getValue())
                            .filter(val -> !StrUtil.hasEmpty(val))
                            .map(HtmlUtil::filter).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]),
                    (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.